# LESS/SASS with Sublime Text

Tags: gulp, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am working with LESS/SASS files

1. I press CTRL+S (in Sublime)
2. .SCSS is compiled to .CSS (GULP)
3. My Sublime Text automatically detects changes inside compiled CSS
4. Sublime Text automatically sends compiled .CSS file to server (with path) (NOT LOCALHOST!) by sFTP (I use this Plugin in ST3)

Does anybody know how I can do this?
Should I use a Plugin to Sublime Text 3/GULP, if so then what Plugin?

Comment: Back when i used sublime-text 3 to edit server-sided I solved tasks like these with winscp. Winscp has a function to spectate a specific directory (recursive) and detect any changes. On any change it will synchronise the server directory and the local one.

Comment: Gulp allows you to watch for changes in your files, and I suspect this is exactly what you use for compiling SCSS to CSS. What's stopping you from using Gulp for the sFTP upload? Try with [gulp-sftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sftp).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to learn SASS or LESS on your localhost, why not create a new **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/)** ?

You just have to go in the `CSS` container, click on the cog (settings), and chose SASS or LESS as your preprocessor.

Then you're good to go !

Comment: Yes but I want learn SASS/LESS on my projects with WordPress Themes :) I have a small knowledge about .SCSS but my BIG problem is "How send automatically changes to FTP after compiling" becouse I dont want manually sending all files created by compilator etc... it to much time..

Comment: Then this isn't related to CSS in any way, this is related to your FTP ! I can't help you with that, sorry :/